# Premiere - Easy way to extend last frame of a video clip

Tags: premiere

Let's say I have a 5 second clip. I want to extend it for an additional 10 seconds, but where the additional 10 seconds simply show the very last frame of my original 5 second clip.

In Camtasia there is an easy way to do it: Just right click and select "Extend frame" (or alternatively the keyboard shortcut is 'E'), then drag the clip out for as long as you like.

But after a bit of googling I haven't managed to find an easy way for Premiere, but surely there is.

P.S. Right now the quickest way I've found (and which I cannot imagine is the quickest way possible) is:

1. Go to the end of the clip.
2. Go back one frame. (So that now that last frame you want is now displayed.) appears
3. Select the clip.
4. Right-click and select "Add frame hold". (You can actually assign a keyboard shortcut for this.)
5. Now the last frame is "held". You can drag it out as far as you want.

Answer (score 5):

What I usually do ...

Locate the frame in the clip you wish to extend, hit <kbd>C</kbd>, the razor tool, cut the frame. Then right click on the cut clip and select 'frame hold'

A popup menu appears, Select hold on, in point (the start of the clip) and select OK.

Then just drag and extend the selected clip for as many additional seconds you wish to extend it for.

Normally I would also unlink the clip before cutting so I keep the audio separate.

Edit:
For CC there are a few more options in the menu to freeze frame the video
You can see here:
http://creativeclouduser.com/creating-freeze-frames-in-premiere-pro/

Comment: Thanks this works, but still takes more steps than is ideal. This is a task I have to perform repeatedly (and I think so do others), so it's hard to believe that there's no quicker way of doing it.

Comment: I believe there is a feature request in Adobe forums for this. Don't know if its already implemented in CC or coming up in the next revision. (I am still using adobe CS6)

Comment: I'm using CC, so perhaps it's already been implemented, but just that I haven't figured it out. I literally started using Premiere yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable "Time Remapping" and make frame before last frame the keyframe. Then just make part of the video which contains last frame more longer.

Answer (score 1):

I just found that in latest version of Adobe Premiere should be option **Insert Frame Hold segment**. However I did not have it in mine... Probably need to update.

You can see how that work here: http://creativeclouduser.com/creating-freeze-frames-in-premiere-pro/

Comment: For your case better will work option **Add Frame Hold** which shall go with option mentioned above. Good luck!

Comment: P.S. Step-by-step you can see variants here: https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/freeze-frame.html

Comment: `Menubar > Adobe Premiere > Keyboard shortcuts`

Answer (score 0):

There is a function that does exactly as you want I think...

In keyboard preferences ... go to clip then video options, finally add frame hold .... and assign that function somewhere .. say Cntrl E for old time sake and you should be in freezeframe heaven ... you can then grab it and drag as long as you like...
enjoy
Robin

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly:

1. Click to select the last visible frame of the clip.
2. From the menu, choose Clip -> Video Options -> Insert Frame Hold.